# Drag excel array formula left then down

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an array formula below:

```
=INDEX(Sup_Missed!$A$4:$FV$78,MATCH(Sheet9!$A$4,Sup_Missed!$A$4:$A$78,0),MATCH(B3,Sup_Missed!$A$4:$FV$4,0))
```

What I did is dragged it left that is why i left the second match reference without lock.  But the problem is now dragging it down, now i have to lock the second match referece(B3) and unlock the first match reference($A$4).  Is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: For shortcuts if you press f4 you cycle between unlocked, fully locked, row lock, column lock.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you're looking for is partial locks:

```
=INDEX(Sup_Missed!$A$4:$FV$78,MATCH(Sheet9!$A4,Sup_Missed!$A$4:$A$78,0),MATCH(B$3,Sup_Missed!$A$4:$FV$4,0))
```

This means that the $A4 reference is locked for column-wise (left-right) dragging. The B$3 reference is locked for row-wise (up-down) dragging.

That said, your question probably belongs on [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com).